New Versions Library problems on setup for daggerhilt + kapt/ksp
Came back to Android after some months and now there is a versions library, on which I already understood how to set up dependencies like livedata, extended icons, navigation etc.
But I'm having a hard time implementing daggerhilt, specifically
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42"

which would require kapt or ksp
And I can't implement neither kapt or ksp
libs.versions
[versions]
agp = "8.3.1"
kotlin = "1.9.10"
coreKtx = "1.10.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleLivedataKtx = "2.3.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.6.1"
activityCompose = "1.7.0"
composeBom = "2023.08.00"

...

ksp = "1.9.10-1.0.13"

hiltAndroid = "2.42"
hiltNavigationCompose = "1.0.0"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-hilt-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose", version.ref = "hiltNavigationCompose" }
androidx-lifecycle-livedata-ktx = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleLivedataKtx" }
...
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }

...

hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }
hilt-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroid" }

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrainsKotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }

project build.gradle
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp) apply false
}

module:app build.gradle
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
}

....

dependencies {

    ...
    //Daggerhilt
    implementation (libs.hilt.android)
    implementation (libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)
    ksp(libs.hilt.compiler)
}

Currently I can sync project, but after trying to build I get error:
> Task :app:kspDebugKotlin FAILED
e: [ksp] No providers found in processor classpath.
e: Error occurred in KSP, check log for detail

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kspDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details


Replace:
ksp(libs.hilt.compiler)

With:
implementation(libs.hilt.android.compiler)

